# HP Laserjet 500 MFP on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, hp

I wanna use HP Laserjet 500 MFP on my Ubuntu 20.04 device. Unfortunately hplip does not support Ubuntu 20.04 yet. Can you help? My error code running the installation script for hplip (`sh ./hplip-3.20.9.run`) is:

```
    Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
    Please wait, this may take several minutes...
    error: Package install command failed with error code 100
```

Also installing hplip from the repository through (`sudo apt-get install hplip`) and running the command `hp-plugin` is not successful. When running the command `hp-setup` the printer does not seem to be recognized.

Comment: The script appears to hide what it's doing. What happens if you run `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5` yourself?

Comment: installation of python-pyt5 as you suggested returns "E: Unable to locate package python-pyqt5"

Comment: unfortunately karel's and N0rbert's links do not help so far, I tried everything. My printer is not being recognized at all when running hp-setup and hp-plugin.

Comment: The HP Laserjet 500 MFP does not exist. Do you mean something like the HP LaserJet Pro 500 Color MFP m570dw? That device is supported by the HPLIP version on 20.04 and by driverless printing.

Comment: On my printer it says: HP Laserjet 500 MFP M525. This printer uses black-white only and no other colors.

Comment: According to [hplip page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) the printer needs HPLIP >3.12.6, so should work out the box on 20.04 LTS. Please remove binary installed HPLIP, connect it to the same network and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal shell.

Update your apt repositories, enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the required dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2 cups libcups2-dev cups-bsd cups-client libcupsimage2-dev libdbus-1-dev build-essential ghostscript openssl libjpeg62-dev libsnmp-dev libtool libusb-1.0-0-dev wget python-imaging policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dbus python-gobject python-dev python-notify python python-reportlab libsane libsane-dev sane-utils xsane
```

Download the HPLIP tarball to your /home/user/Downloads directory:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.20.9/hplip-3.20.9.tar.gz/download
```

Go to the directory where you downloaded the HPLIP tarball:

```
cd ~/home/user/Downloads
```

Uncompress the tarball, enter this command:

```
tar xvfz hplip-3.20.9.tar.gz
```

This will create a directory with the same name as the tarball file.

Change your working directory to the hplip-3.20.9 directory.

```
cd hplip-3.20.9
```

Configure the development environment and checks that your system is ready to install HPLIP:

```
./configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --enable-udev-acl-rules --enable-qt4 --disable-libusb01_build --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build
```

Compile the HPLIP source, enter this command:

```
make
```

Run make install, enter this command:

```
sudo make install
```

Add user name to "lp" group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp $USER
```

Restart your PC (or) Logout and Login.

f you are going to be setting up a printer with USB and the printer is already plugged in, you will need to do one of the following:

Unlpug and re-plug in the USB printer, or Restart your PC.

Failure to do this will cause your USB printer to not be detected by HPLIP.

Continue using hp-setup:

```
sudo hp-setup
```

The first step is to select the printer connection type.

Next the setup tool will display printers detected (depending on the connection type selected)

The PPD files (drivers) which are most similar to your printer are displayed. Select the appropriate PPD file for your printer.

Enter your printer information.

Click FINISH to complete the printer setup process.

Answer (score 0):

This device is probably an HP LaserJet Enterprise 500 MFP m525f. It has an AirPrint service so will do driverless printing; connect it to the network and execute the command `driverless`. The output is a URI. Substitute the output in `lpadmin -p m525 -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`. Test printing.